# Xcode 6.4 Framework

Tags: objective-c, architecture, frameworks, arm64, iphone-64bit

I cannot seem to find the solution to this problem.  I created a new custom framework in Objective-C and when I included it in a sample project, I am getting the following messages/errors on compilation:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/location/CustomFrameworkAPI.framework/CustomFrameworkAPI, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/location/CustomFrameworkAPI.framework/CustomFrameworkAPI (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CustomFrameworkAPI", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I checked the architecture of the framework, I'm seeing that x86_64 is part of the custom framework that I have built.  Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
MacBook-Pro:CustomFrameworkAPI.framework user$ file CustomFrameworkAPI 
CustomFrameworkAPI: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
CustomFrameworkAPI (for architecture armv7):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm
CustomFrameworkAPI (for architecture arm64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error that you posted says that the framework you are using **CustomFrameworkAPI** referred in **ViewController** is not built in such a way that it supports 64-bit environment.

Kindly check your framework's architecture on which it is built upon.

Use **lipo** command to check the architecture of the framework.

This might not be the exact solution or answer to your problem.

Thanks.